# Expressing a vector in terms of vectors from orthonormal bases.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal

I have come across a statement in my book, that doesn't seem obvious to me.

Lets say i have an orthonormal basis $z = {z_1,z_2}$ for a subspace $V$
and a another set of vectors $q = {q_1, q_2} $ thats the orthonormal basis for the complement $V^⊥$ of $V$.

How might i express a vector $e_1$ as $e_1 = z + q$ where $q \in V^⊥$, $z \in V$.

EDIT:
The question is then how can one fine $e_1$?

Comment: What is the statement which doesn't seem obvious to you? The statement that it is possible to write $e = z+q$? This is essentially the definition of direct sum. Since the total space is the direct sum $V \oplus V^\perp$, there are unique $z$ and $q$ with this property.

Comment: Yes the statement you assumed in your comment. How can i find this sum?

Comment: $z=\langle e_1,z_1 \rangle z_1+\langle e_,z_2 \rangle z_2$ and $q=\langle e_1,q_1 \rangle q_1+\langle e_,q_2 \rangle q_2$